# Scaleable M code to create n number of columns based on the unique values in a column?

Tags: data-structures, powerquery, data-analysis, m, dummy-variable

I have a large dataset filled with customer purchase data. There are two columns that are of specific interest to me: the date of a purchase and the order of the purchase (1 means it was the customer's first purchase, 2 means it was the customer's second purchase, and so on).

I would like to create a column for each unique purchase order value, and fill it with the corresponding date.

The end result would be n number of columns named "1st purchase date", "2nd purchase date", [...], "n purchase date" for each customer.

This is what the table looks like currently:

[image]

This is a sample of the desired output:

[image]

Apologies if the table formatting is unclear.

I don't want to do this manually, as the purchase order variable is variable. I am however conscious of the fact that there might be too many columns in the end, so if it's possible to add a limit to the number of columns, that would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to do this manually, but it's arduous and limiting (the max value of the purchase order is currently >60).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't post samples as images. Post as text so we don't have to retype things to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, click select the Purchase Order Column

Transform ... pivot column...

for Values Column choose Date, and in Advanced Options pick Don't aggregate

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Apologies for the table as images, I tried to format the tables in the original text but they came out jumbled.